# Show date of music files creation in folder

Tags: windows-7

When I open folder with music files, Windows 7 instead of showing usual details : Modification date, Type, Size of file shows me : Title, Author and Album, how to show files in usual manner ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the view is already set to details mode, so right click on any header item, and choose 'More...' at the bottom of the menu. That brings up a dialogue box that lets you choose which columns to show and what order.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can tweak it the following way:

**A.** Right click on the bar where the name dropdown appears and click 'more'.

[image]

**B.** Click the box to include or exclude as you wish.

[image]